# Math with mixed variable data types

Tags: objective-c

I am calculating a percent complete with variables of mixed data types.

```
int incompleteCritical = 12;
int total = 24;
float progress = 0;

NSLog(@"Incomplete Total: %d", incompleteCritical);
NSLog(@"Total Total: %d", total);

if (total > 0) {
    progress = ((float)incompleteCritical/(float)total)*100;
    NSLog(@"Progress: %d", progress);
}
```

The console output is as follows:

```
2011-01-11 10:02:59.993 [18570:207] Incomplete Total: 12
2011-01-11 10:02:59.993 [18570:207] Total Total: 24
2011-01-11 10:02:59.994 [18570:207] Progress: 0
```

Why is Progress not returning "50"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong format string in your `NSLog` statement. `%d` is used for integers. You need to use `%f` when you log floating point numbers. (T[here are extra parameters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) to use to limit the number of decimal places, etc.)